# emacs lucid vs. gtk and -iconic -xrm

Tags: window

The `emacs` command from emacs23-lucid under wheezy honors the

```
-iconic -xrm '*iconX: 3350' -xrm '*iconY: 300' -xrm '*bitmapIcon: off'
```

command-line arguments. But emacs from emacs24-gtk under jessie does not.
(The version from emacs24-gtk under jessie does handle `-geometry` but handles
it incorrectly, or at least differently than emacs23-lucid under wheezy. It
doesn't handle the `-5` in `-geometry 80x24-5+200` correctly.)

I don't know if this is a gtk-vs-lucid thing, a 23-vs-24 thing, or a
wheezy-vs-jessie thing.

I use this to create a panel of small Emacs icons with just the hostnames for
all of my machines on my desktop. (I run twm.)

Since the gtk version of Emacs seems to be the future (and some machine that I
use only have the gtk version; I can't change that because I don't maintain
them), I'd like to migrate to the gtk version.

How does one achieve the equivalent of the above command-line arguments with
the gtk version?

Comment: It may also be an issue with the GTK version being used since GTK seems to [break the -geometry option](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=760944) [then and when](https://sourceforge.net/p/roxterm/bugs/125/#6e97) which even [makes some software developers to give up their own projects](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=827768#5). Nevertheless the aforementioned case can't affect a Wheezy-vs-Jessie thing since it [happened only recently](https://bugs.debian.org/821357) and the bugs only affect Debian Unstable/Testing at the moment.